# Алгоритм сортировки двумерного массива методом простого выбора

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дана действительная матрица размером (n,m), упорядочить (переставить) строки матрицы, по неубыванию значений первых элементов строк методом простого выбора. Вот что получилось:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int **a = NULL;
    int n, m, x = 0, y;
    cout << "Введите число строк массива:  ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите число столбцов массива:  ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n";
    if (n <= 0 || m <= 0)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Невозможно создать массив нулевой размерности. Введите другой размер массива \n";
            cout << "Введите число строк массива:  ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Введите число столбцов массива:  ";
            cin >> m;
            cout << "\n";
        } while (n <= 0 || m <= 0);
    }
    try
    {
        a = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = new int[n];
    }
        catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Недостаточно памяти! \n";
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
    cout << "Заполним массив случайныйм образом.. \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i][j] = -5 + rand() % 10;// ввод элементов
//------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "Был введен следующий массив : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int b,i,j,k,min;       не работает правильно сортировка простым выбором!
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    min=i;
        for (k=0; k<n-1; k++){
        if (a[min][0]>a[min+1][0]){
        min=k;
            for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            b=a[min][j];
            a[min][j]=a[min+1][j];
            a[min+1][j]=b;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "Отсортированный массив : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[] a[i] ;
    delete[] a;
    system("pause");

}
```

Это код для сортировки строк методом простого выбора двумерного массива по первому элементу каждой строки. Он работает и переставляет строки, но не сортирует по первому столбцу матрицы. Я не знаю почему он не работает, провёл множество манипуляций с кодом, но не помогло.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?